# Facebook profil picture simple api

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api

I start to code in PHP and I am facing a problem, I used classic method to get User Profil Picture :

https://graph.facebook.com/mark/picture

But as you know, Facebook with little regard for small coders like me. They have cleared this easy method. Now I have to connect on their API to get a facebook profile picture.

I have used fil_get_content on the Mobile Facebook site to retrieve the profile image, but it asks for a captcha.

I am FORCED to go through their API, also I created a APP_ID and APP_SECRET but I do not know how. Despite all the tutorials I've tried these last two hours.

If someone would have a solution, it would be nice.

Thank you, good evening.

Comment: what exactly is your question? if you want to get a user profile picture, then you have to authorize the user - which is explained in the official docs. even before the change, you would not have been allowed to do ANYTHING with the profile picture without authorization of the user, for privacy reasons.

Comment: You just can not use the `username` any more to request any information about users – you need to use the user id instead. https://graph.facebook.com/4/picture redirects to Mark’s profile picture.

Answer (score 0):

Use following Code  to get your profile picture

```
 $request = new FacebookRequest(
      $session,
      'GET',
      '/me',
      array(
        'fields' => 'picture'
      )
    );

    $response = $request->execute();
    $graphObject = $response->getGraphObject();
    /* handle the result */
```

Now print your response using $response variable.

In a response you got a url.